# How to remove ellipses (...) in Ghidra disassembly listing display?

Tags: configuration, customization, reverse-engineering, ghidra

[Ghidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghidra) often truncates text in the disassembly listing display with ellipses (...) as pictured below in several examples:

[image: examples with ellipses]
[image: ellipses at register content]
[image: ellipses at address]

My question is this: **How can I make Ghidra stop doing this?**

I have looked all over in the extensive configuration options and I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is a button in the top right of the listing window:

[image: arrow to button "Edit the Listing fields"]

When you click the button, you are presented with this:

[image: Editing the listing fields]

You can drag the borders of the gray rectangles in order to adjust the widths of those respective fields. Whatever field you are currently clicked onto in the disassembly listing will be highlighted as peach in the gray rectangles.

Comment: Is there a way to temporarily show the entire field? Sometimes the operand or EOL comment are _very_ long, and no matter how much I drag, are still truncated.

Comment: @SRobertJames - I've not been in Ghidra for many months now, so I personally am not sure. You should post your question as a new Question and could link to this one as an example of not quite meeting your need. Hope you are able to figure something out!

Comment: @SRobertJames: Alternatively you could copy the content to the clipboard with ctrl+c and paste it into a text editor.

Comment: This answer made my day !  Thank you very much.